# Getting Nil While Trying to Set Class Label Property | UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I keep getting unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when I run this code.

What I am trying to do is get the first property in an array of objects so I use .map to get the first property which is "workoutName"

Then I try to set the label in the CellData class to this value but keep getting that it found nil.

I appreciate all help I can get.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var workoutName = workouts.map { $0.workoutName }

        let cell = CellData()

        cell.workoutNameLabel.text! = workoutName[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }
```

Cell Data Class

```
import UIKit

class CellData: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var workoutNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfSetsNumberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfRepsNumberLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you verify if you've connected the `workoutNameLabel` to the appropriate UILabel in the interface builder?

Comment: @Andrej It is properly connected :)

Comment: The cell won't trigger awakeFromNib and setup all the IBOutlet properties just in initialization due to some race conditions, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set class variable into CellData class and set it in awakeFromNib since awakeFromNib won't happen before the cellForRow is finished, so you can be almost 100% sure that the label will be nil.. try this:

```
import UIKit

class CellData: UITableViewCell {

    //someLableValue string
    var labelValueText: String?

    @IBOutlet weak var workoutNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfSetsNumberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfRepsNumberLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        workoutNameLabel.text = labelValueText
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

then you jsut set the variable `labelValueText` in cellForRowMethod in UITableViewController class

Comment: It works but I'm not getting anything in my cell. probably something to do with workouts.map